# Best link to start with jquery mobile and phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to start with jqueymobile and phonegap. I looked into many links but i didnt get proper info. Can some one provide me the best link to setting up the eclipse for phonegap and start working with phonegap and jquery mobile. i am very new to the jquery mobile and phonegap. please help me in getting started.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Official link to make a game : 
https://build.phonegap.com/blog/my-first-mobile-game-in-html-with-phonegap-build

Or

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can check this. Code example is also available here.
http://www.alltechstories.com/setup-phonegap-eclipse-develop-first-android-game/